# Members in partial class cannot be identified C#

Tags: c#

I am writing 2 partial classes like below:
PartialClassOne.cs:

```
    namespace PartialClassBasic
    {
        public partial class PartialClass
        {
            private string firlstName;

            public string FirlstName
            {
                get { return firlstName; }
                set { firlstName = value; }
            }
            private string lastName;

            public string LastName
            {
                get { return lastName; }
                set { lastName = value; }
            }
        }
    }
```

ParticalClassTwo.cs:

```
namespace PartialClassBasic
{
    public partial class ParticalClass
    {
        public string getFullName()
        {
            return FirstName + ", " + LastName;
        }
    }
}
```

when I build this solution, I got 2 compile error message like below:

```
The name 'FirstName' does not exist in the current context
The name 'LastName' does not exist in the current context
```

so, who can tell me it there something wrong with my code?

thanks!

Comment: The first class is called PartialClass, the second one Parti**c**alClass. It is a typo error

Answer (score 1):

You made a typo.

```
public partial class ParticalClass
```

Should be:

```
public partial class PartialClass
```

Also,

```
public string FirlstName
```

Should be:

```
public string FirstName
```